# Resources to learn OOP for WordPress plugins, custom post types, etc

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

In a plugin, I need to create a custom post type and the associated admin menu modifications with a class rather than procedural code. What is the basic skeleton that I need to build off of in order to do so, and how does that class get hooked into WordPress (i.e., how do I do the "add_action('init','register_my_custom_post_type'), etc. with a class)?

Comment: This very resource: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bplugin-development%5d%20%2bclass%20%2bextends%20is%3aa

Comment: Just for fun I did a quick google search »wordpress oop«. I'm not going to post links here, but I can tell you, the first page alone is very resourceful. You might want to start there, besides looking deeper into what WPSE already offers - like brasofilo suggested. Another hint would be looking for those existing wordpress plugin boilerplates/skeletons.

Answer (score 0):

> (i.e., how do I do the `add_action('init','register_my_custom_post_type')`, etc. with a class)?

You pass the callback from *inside* the class, using `$this`:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_my_custom_post_type' ) );
```